# PHP artisan migration error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i m executing PHP `artisan migrate` I'm getting following error

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Social>php artisan migrate help
>
> [ErrorException]
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\Social\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/A
>   uth/AuthController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Social>php artisan migrate
>
> [ErrorException]
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\Social\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/A
>   uth/AuthController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Soci

how to solve this problem please help???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use Laravel auth system by adding `Auth::routes();` (Laravel 5.3+) or `Route::auth();` (Laravel 5.2) to the routes file, but you didn't create controllers and views. So, you'll need to remove the line from the `web.php` and run this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

After that put `Auth::routes();` back to the `web.php`. Or `Route::auth();` to the `routes.php` if you're using Laravel 5.2 and lower.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: He's got an old version (~5.2) according to the name of auth controller  `AuthController.php`. Routes are set in `/app/Http/routes.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Run composer install in your root project folder (or php composer.phar install)